# How to pass an instance driver generated by selenium object into a wizard in odoo

Tags: python, selenium, odoo, selenium-firefoxdriver

Thanks to everyone who saw this issue. I click a button to trigger the execution of a function that uses `selenium` in this function to create a `driver`.

With this driver, I can drag and drop pictures, click buttons, send SMS captcha to the phone without opening the Firefox browser window.

When that's all over, I need to jump a wizard to get my users to enter the captcha sent to the phone.But after we load the wizard from the odoo interface and enter the captcha and click confirm button, I need to enter the captcha value into the page that I just opened with the `driver`.

How can I get the previous `driver`? What good solutions are there, thanks.

**This is my function to use `selenium`**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

class SaleOrderSend(models.Model)
    _name='sale.order.send'

    @api.multi
    def handel_web_send_captcha(self):

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')


        driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        driver.get(sign_url)  
        time.sleep(15)

        ac1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("es-drag-seal")[0]
        ac2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('es-sign-date-field')
        time.sleep(1)
        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(ac1, ac2).perform()

        time.sleep(2)
        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button//span[text()='Submit']")
        submit_button.click()

        time.sleep(3)
        driver.switch_to.frame(0)
        short_message = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Sign']")
        short_message.click()

        time.sleep(3)
        send_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-form-item__content']//button//span[text()='Get_Code']")
        send_code.click()

        time.sleep(2)
        driver.close()

        action = {
            'name': _("Please enter the verification code"),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'signature.code',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'target': 'new'
        }
        return action
```

**And this is my py file and xml file in wizard**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

class SignatureCode(models.Model):
    _name = 'signature.code'
    _description = 'Signature Code'

    sign_code = fields.Char('Sign Code')
    sign_url = fields.Char('Sign Url')

    @api.multi
    def confirm_sign_code(self):
        """
        Enter the user's captcha code into the browser page you just opened using selenium.
        :return:
        """
        sign_code = self.sign_code

        # How do I get to the previous driver?  driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="signature_code_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Signature Code Form View</field>
        <field name="model">signature.code</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Signature Code Form View">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="sign_code" required="1" readonly="0"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
                <footer>
                    <button string="Confirm" name="confirm_sign_code" type="object" default_focus="1"
                            class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses Python's class properties to store the already generated driver.

In the operation, we first click one button to jump to the wizard, in which we have two buttons.

First click the first button to trigger method `send_code`,in which we modify the class property like `SignatureCode.driver = driver`.

In the second step, we click confirm button to trigger method `confirm_sign_code`,in which we use `driver = self.driver` to call back the previously saved `driver` in the class property.

Now we have successfully gotten the previously opened browser interface `driver` and can close it in a later operation.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api, _
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from odoo.exceptions import UserError
import os

class SignatureCode(models.TransientModel):
    """
    This class is used to receive the captcha when signing
    """
    _name = 'signature.code'
    _description = 'Signature Code'
    driver = None # Define an initialized class property


    sign_code = fields.Char('Sign Code')
    sign_url = fields.Char('Sign Url')
    have_sent = fields.Boolean('Have Sent') # Whether to send an authentication code
    manual_sign_id = fields.Many2one('manual.sign',string='Manual Sign')

    @api.multi
    def send_code(self):
        """
        Send a code
        :return:
        """
        # No interface operation
        if self.driver:
            try:
                self.driver.close()
            except:
                pass
            finally:
                SignatureCode.driver = None
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')

        # Open the browser, no interface, and don't let selenium generate logs
        driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options,service_log_path=os.devnull)

# This step is key, once the property has been generated, we need to use the class
# property modification method to save this property to the class for the next call
        SignatureCode.driver = driver

        self._cr.commit()
        driver.get(self.sign_url)
        time.sleep(15)


        if not self.manual_sign_id.have_got:
            first_confirm_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[10]/div/div[3]/span/button/span")
            first_confirm_button.click()
            self.manual_sign_id.have_got = True
            self._cr.commit()
            time.sleep(2)

        bottom = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[9]/span/img[@class='toBottom']")
        if bottom:
            bottom[0].click()
            time.sleep(3)

        ac1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("es-drag-seal")[0]
        ac2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/span")
        time.sleep(1)
        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(ac1, ac2).perform()

        time.sleep(2)
        submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button//span[text()='submit']")
        submit_button.click()

        time.sleep(3)
        driver.switch_to.frame(0)
        short_message = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='sign']")
        short_message.click()

        time.sleep(3)
        send_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-form-item__content']//button//span[text()='get code']")
        send_code.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.have_sent = True
        self._cr.commit()
        raise UserError(_('The authentication code has been sent to the phone, please check the receipt'))


    @api.multi
    def confirm_sign_code(self):
        """
        validation code
        :return:
        """
        if not self.have_sent:
            raise UserError(_('Please send the verification code first'))
        if not self.sign_code:
            raise UserError(_('Please fill sign code'))
        sign_code = self.sign_code

        # Since we have previously modified class properties with classes, as long as we
        # don't close the wizard, the class properties that have been changed will not be   
        # released.
        driver = self.driver

        # Enter the verification code
        input_code = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='el-input']//input[@class='el-input__inner' and @placeholder='Enter the verification code']")
        input_code.send_keys(sign_code) # Enter the verification code
        time.sleep(2)

        # confirm
        confirm_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='realname-form-opt']//button//span[text()='confirm']")
        confirm_button.click()
        time.sleep(4)

        # Here you have to judge whether the captcha is correct or not, based on the web
        # domain changes
        fail_tip = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='van-toast van-toast--middle van-toast--fail']")
        if fail_tip: #failed
            fail_msg = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='van-toast__text' and text()='failed']")
            if fail_msg:
                raise UserError(_('Verification code is incorrect, please re-enter'))
            else:
                raise UserError(_('Too many verifications, please review again'))

        # close
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.close()

        return {
            'type':'ir.actions.client',
            'tag':'reload'
        }
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="signature_code_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Signature Code Form View</field>
        <field name="model">signature.code</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Signature Code Form View">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="have_sent" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="sign_code" readonly="0"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <button name="send_code" string="Send Code"
                                    attrs="{'invisible':[('have_sent','=',True)]}"
                                    type="object" default_focus="1" class="btn-primary"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
                <footer>
                    <button string="Confirm" name="confirm_sign_code" type="object" default_focus="1"
                            class="btn-primary"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

pychong

On this method `def handel_web_send_captcha(self)` added the `code` just like this,

```
ctx = self.env.context.copy()
ctx.update({'previous_driver': driver})
action = {
    'name': _("Please enter the verification code"),
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'res_model': 'signature.code',
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'target': 'new',
    'context': ctx,
}
```

And on this `def confirm_sign_code(self)` method, Get the Previous Driver Data like this,

```
driver = self._context.get('previous_driver')
print("\n\n driver ", driver)
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry partner,in context, the data must be jsonable.When returen an action,the error message is ```the context must be jsonable```.However,I've found another good solution that uses Python's class properties to store the already generated driver,I'll answer that question in detail later.

Comment: I have other solutions too, just like 'sign_code' take the another filed with 'previous_driver' after that you can save the default of drive while the return to action.so once you access the 'previous_driver' field with self.previous_driver you will get the previous drive name.

Comment: But what are the fields that can store objects of the class?